# SF Symbol in Mac Application not shown when running

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, macos-catalina

I'm trying to use SF symbols as icons in a Mac OS X toolbar using Swift and Interface Builder. I've exported the icons from the SF Symbols App and imported them in the Xcode project and added them to the Assets catalog.
When I define the toolbar in Interface Builder I can use the icon in a toolbar button and it shows up in the preview from the Nib file (see screenshot below).

But when I run the application, no image is shown and I get an error:
`Could not find image named 'play.rectangle'.`

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,
Don

[image: screenshot]

Comment: For the moment, apparently, SF Symbols are not supported in macOS platforms. Only iOS12 onwards

Comment: Can you share the screenshot of Asset Catalog with play.rectangle selected?